# checkall jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, kendo-ui

Here is what I have so far for the check all checkboxes and these checkboxes are in a dropdownlist.

```
 _popup: function () {
            e.fn._popup.call(this), this.popup.one("open", function () {
                this.wrapper = c.wrap(this.element).addClass("km-popup")
            });

            // Modify popup to include a "Select All" checkbox.
            $(this.popup.element).children("ul:first-child").before("<ul class='k-list k-reset' unselectable='on' style='overflow: auto;'><li class='k-item' unselectable='on'><input id='selectall' type='checkbox' /><span>Selected</span></li></ul><hr/>");

            // Attach event handler to "Select All checkbox.
              $("#selectall").bind('change', function(){
                if($(this).prop('checked')){
                    $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
                }else{
                    $(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
                }
            });
```

this updates the check boxes to visually appear on the screen all selected or deselected. I have a button that tells me the state of the viewmodel ie if the checkboxes are true or false. The problem is, is that with the selectall working and checking everything, the viewmodel is not getting updated with those changes ie everytime you click the select all checkbox everything stays false when the test button is clicked no matter if they are checked or not. I need some way to update the viewmodel when I click select all. The whole of the program is pretty complex but if you need more to understand my issue let me know.

here is what my viewmodel has in it

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    options: [{ text: "test1", value: 1, selected: false },
                { text: "test2", value: 2, selected: false },
                { text: "test3", value: 3, selected: false },
                { text: "test4", value: 4, selected: false }
                ]
});
```

Comment: so if you manually click a checkbox it will change the value?

Comment: Is there not any way you can update your viewModel too?

Comment: @wirey yeah if you manually click a checkbox the value will be updated in the viewmodel because I am using data-bind="source: options" for the dropdownlist input and for the checkbox template I am using data-bind='checked: selected' so everything should be bound

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
  $("#selectall").bind('change', function(){

        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $(".checkbox").not(':checked').click();
        }else{
            $(".checkbox:checked").click();
        }
  });
```

Comment: when trying this and clicking selectall only the top checkbox gets filled in but that top checkbox is updating in the viewmodel I just need a way to check the rest of the checkboxes now.

Comment: @ChrisStopher Oh.. hmm.. let me create a fiddle to see if I need to loop

Comment: @ChrisStopher it should work..  heres a fiddle for you to see how it works http://jsfiddle.net/eC3t6/